# javascript or PHP detect iPhone 5S

Tags: javascript, php, iphone

I would like to know if there is a way of detecting whether an iPhone is an iPhone 5 or iPhone 5s. I currently check via useragent, and then when It's established that an iPhone is in use i then run this quick check

JS

```
var iphone4 = (window.screen.height == (960 / 2));
var iphone5 = (window.screen.height == (1136 / 2));
```

As the iPhone 5 has a bigger screen it's simple. But i need to know the difference between an iPhone 5 and an iPhone 5s.

I've looked around for this and can not seem to get an answer.

EDITED

I Just tried this

```
txt = "<p>Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Platform: " + navigator.platform + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent + "</p>";

document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=txt;
```

But the data returned was just generic USER AGENT information. Not chip type or device model.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html

5s is the same as 5.   Both should be 568 X 320.  It will be displayed with double the resolution, but don't develop to those numbers.  Just develop to the 568 X 320 and you'll be fine.

Comment: I need to know the difference between 5 and 5S, it isn't for display purposes, it is to do with hardware.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use "navigator" object

```
console.log(navigator.appVersion);
```

just log navigator object and check. may you find something interesting for you

Comment: I tried you solution but to no avail, i've updated my question showing your solution i've tried.

Comment: yes it gives you information about Operating System and not about device.